# How to find *all* startup programs on Windows 10?

Tags: boot, windows-10

I've checked the "Start-up" tab under Task Manager, the "Services" tab in `msconfig`, and the startup folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`) but there's an app that keeps coming up whenever I boot (Patriot Dashboard) that's not listed in any of those places.

Where can I find the rest of the startup apps?

[image]

Comment: [Ways to start a program at windows startup?](https://superuser.com/q/864438)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of all software that starts automatically when Windows 7 starts?](http://superuser.com/questions/507194/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-software-that-starts-automatically-when-windows-7-start), [How do I manage what programs startup in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/490873/how-do-i-manage-what-programs-startup-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) for **Windows** from **Sysinternals**

[image]

Comment: Awesome. That found it in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: Have issue that my task manager is starting with every boot, but even Autoruns can't find it. I also checked all Windows 10 locations for autostart without luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MaksimLuzik You must post your own question with all the details

Comment: I think I have found it. Windows 10 remembers your last open applications, even after shutdown and starts them on every boot. My task manager was due to this fact starting every time, even though it wasn't in any autorun config.

Answer (score 8):

You should try [`Autoruns for Windows`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

> This utility, which has the most comprehensive knowledge of auto-starting locations of any startup monitor, shows you what programs are configured to run during system bootup or login, and when you start various built-in Windows applications like Internet Explorer, Explorer and media players. These programs and drivers include ones in your startup folder, Run, RunOnce, and other Registry keys. Autoruns reports Explorer shell extensions, toolbars, browser helper objects, Winlogon notifications, auto-start services, and much more. Autoruns goes way beyond other autostart utilities.

Just search for `Patriot Dashboard` on Everything tab and `Autoruns` will locate it.